# Decrypt CryptProtectData in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, winapi, cryptprotectdata

I'm making a program to recover password data in Chrome. I have access to the actual machine, and I know the schema of the password/username document.

When I list the password_value table from the logins, it shows a bunch of weird, heavily encrypted strings that crashes sqlite3 and breaks my console. From sources online (https://superuser.com/questions/655573/decrypt-google-chrome-passwords), it says this data was encrypted with the CryptProtectData function in the Windows API.

How would I reverse this function via C#? If you need more information, I'll give it to you.

Comment: What do you use to connect to SQLite from C#?

Comment: Windows default SQLite api wrapper, System.Data.SQLite i think

Comment: There is no "Windows default SQLite api wrapper". System.Data.SQLite is not related to Windows

Comment: C#'s wrapper of the raw SQLite C api, sorry "i messed up" but you could clearly tell what i meant

Comment: You can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61333362/403671 translate in C# it's relatively easy, and replace `win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData...` by `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(master_key, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);`